# how to set the number of decimals in python?

Tags: python, numbers, decimal

I have a question in python.

I made a code in python and want to set the number of decimals to a specific number (say n) at the beginning of the code to have all my number result with n number of decimals. In fact, I am looking for something like "format long" or "format short" in MATLAB. Something like a command that I can set at the beginning of the code to have all my numbers in the way I want.

Thanks!

Comment: this one doesn't help as I need to apply it on every single parameter I want to get as an output number. I am looking for something general that affects every number in the code.

Comment: Do you care about the numbers' actual representation, or just how they're displayed on the screen? I still think the proposed duplicate is the right answer, but if you're using scientific libraries there might be another solution in e.g. `numpy`. If so, you should add a relevant tag to your question.